# Error deploying Django migrations to Heroku

Tags: heroku, django-models

I have a DJANGO app.  It is hosted on heroku.  The site is working on the local server.  I have made some changes to a django project.  When deploying to heroku via github it fails.

The reason for the failure is below.  But, I can't seem to work out how to fix it.

Please help with the fix:

````
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation: insert or update on table "product_product" violates foreign key constraint "product_product_units_of_supply_id_47b2bb72_fk_list_supp"
DETAIL:  Key (units_of_supply_id)=(6) is not present in table "list_supply_units".
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 417, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 90, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 253, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 126, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 156, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 236, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 125, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 225, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 618, in alter_field
    self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 196, in _alter_field
    super()._alter_field(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 853, in _alter_field
    self.execute(self._create_fk_sql(model, new_field, "_fk_%(to_table)s_%(to_column)s"))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 151, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "product_product" violates foreign key constraint "product_product_units_of_supply_id_47b2bb72_fk_list_supp"
DETAIL:  Key (units_of_supply_id)=(6) is not present in table "list_supply_units". ```

Please help to solve this problem.

AC
````

Comment: Please don't SHOUT. Titles are automatically rendered prominently, there is no need for all caps.

Comment: Please show us the migration that is failing. You are either trying to insert data that violates a constraint, or add a constraint to data that violates that constraint.

Comment: I resolved this by editing the migrations file in the offending file.  I then backed up all data and dropped the database.  After this, I imported the data into a new database